# Bash Output at the end of program

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash scripting and I'm working on a bash script right now that's supposed to download a list of files from a server using the scp command. However, there's no guarantee that the file is there, so I want to be able to output the list of files that were not found. Currently, I'm doing this to output the error message:

```
for FILENAME in $@ do
scp $SERVER:/home/usr/$FILENAME .
  if [ $? -ne 0 ] then
    echo "WARNING: $FILENAME was not found in $SERVER."
  fi
done
```

The code above works to my knowledge, but the problem I'm having is that due to how scp works, there's already going to be a ton of text on the screen (since each scp command is going to show the 100% downloaded line) and I probably will miss a warning message or two. Is there a easy way for me to have all of the warning messages print at the very end, having it list which files were not found?

EDIT: I forgot to clarify why I'm using an echo instead of the default "file not found" - my code is actually supposed to look in multiple locations if it can't find it in the first place. So, the more complete version looks kind of like this:

```
for FILENAME in $@ do
scp $SERVER:/home/usr/$FILENAME .
  if [ $? -ne 0 ] then
      scp $SERVER:/home/usr/documents/$FILENAME .
      if [ $? -ne 0 ] then
         scp $SERVER:/home/usr/documents/local/$FILENAME .
         if [ $? -ne 0 ] then
           echo "WARNING: $FILENAME was not found in $SERVER."
         fi
      fi
  fi
done
```

If it doesn't find it in the first location, that's fine, but I only want it to throw an error if I can't find it in any of the locations.

Comment: Use `-q` to tell `scp` to be quiet? Loop over the arguments again at the end and see if the local files exist? Don't echo in that `if` append to an array variable and print that array at the end? echo to standard error instead and pipe that to a file or pipe standard output to `/dev/null` from `scp`?

Comment: @Etan Reisner: it seems like `-q` only hides the progress meter, not the stderr.

Comment: The stderr from scp about the file not existing/failing is likely information the OP actually wants (since it does the job for them). Unless scp stuffs other non-failure information on stderr too that is.

Comment: @EtanReisner I only need to know which files were not found in any of the listed locations (see edit in original post), so I don't want every single error message because if the file is not found in the first directory, but is later found in the second or third directory, then the error message of the first failure would only throw me off since eventually I did find the file, just not where I originally wanted it.

Comment: Ok. So `-q` isn't enough but if you don't care about the progress meters it is still useful and if you don't care about the scp errors either then you can just redirect them all away `2>/dev/null` and only have your error output at the end. You could do the other things I suggested instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (though not the most efficient solution) is to simply check for file existence at the end.

Add this after the original loop:

```
for FILENAME in $@ do
    if [ -s "$FILENAME" ] then
        echo "WARNING: $FILENAME was not found in $SERVER." >&2
    fi
done
```

Alternatively if the normal scp output isn't interesting (and you don't care about other potential scp failures) then the original loop could become:

```
for FILENAME in $@ do
scp -q $SERVER:/home/usr/$FILENAME . 2>/dev/null
  if [ $? -ne 0 ] then
      scp -q $SERVER:/home/usr/documents/$FILENAME . 2>/dev/null
      if [ $? -ne 0 ] then
         scp -q $SERVER:/home/usr/documents/local/$FILENAME . 2>/dev/null
         if [ $? -ne 0 ] then
           echo "WARNING: $FILENAME was not found in $SERVER."
         fi
      fi
  fi
done
```

If you do want the scp output (normal or error or both) but **also** want a succinct list of missing files at the end you could do this:

```
missing_files=()
for FILENAME in $@ do
scp $SERVER:/home/usr/$FILENAME .
  if [ $? -ne 0 ] then
      scp $SERVER:/home/usr/documents/$FILENAME .
      if [ $? -ne 0 ] then
         scp $SERVER:/home/usr/documents/local/$FILENAME .
         if [ $? -ne 0 ] then
           missing_files+=("$FILENAME")
         fi
      fi
  fi
done

echo 'Missing files:'
printf %s\\n "${missing_files[@]}"
```

Comment: The last one was exactly what I was looking for; thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could redirect the `scp` command's stderr to a file, then `cat` out the file at the end of the script:

```
for FILENAME in $@ do
scp $SERVER:/home/usr/$FILENAME . 2>> /some/dir/error.log
  if [ $? -ne 0 ] then
    echo "WARNING: $FILENAME was not found in $SERVER."
  fi
done

cat /some/dir/error.log
rm /some/dir/error.log
```

Comment: Good catch. We are in a loop. Corrected.

Comment: What does the number 2 in the 2>> mean? The 2>> /some/dir/error.log seems to take all of the output and put it into a log file, then outputing it at the end, but I only really need to know which files failed to be found in all listed locations (see edit on my original post)

Comment: Command line programs on Linux have two outputs that both go to the command line by default. Stdout, which is normal talky talk from the program. Stderr is the errors reported by the program. You can redirect either or both of these to a file by using `>` (overwrite the file) or `>>` (append to the file). `1>` is stderr redirect and `2>` is stderr redirect. You can also you `&>` to redirect both.

Comment: @JNevill Following up on that, if I use 2>>, which from your explaination redirects stderr, will that affect my following line, the if statement that checks the exit code? Or does redirecting stderr not affect the exit code still being returned?

Comment: That won't affect the error code check. It just redirects the messages. Sorry for the late reply, too.